# Graphing interactions between relations between variables and the effect of power distance

Tags: r

I have conducted a study with 152 responses. The study uses scale items to measure: organizational identification (independent variable), power distance (moderation variable) and voice (dependent variable).

First I used linear regression modeling to establish the relationship between my independent variable and my dependent variable.

Then I used linear regression modeling to assess the moderation effect of power distance on the relationship between my independent and dependent variables.

[image]

Now, I have gotten to the point where I would like to graph these interactions. I have seen some studies present graphs where they show the linear relationship between variables x & y, and also show the linear relationship between x & y when moderated by z (two lines on the same graph to display these relationships).

The image included is from a study conducted measuring different predictors of voice (Detert & Burris, 2007). It is pretty much what I am trying to accomplish, Voice would be the Y axis, with organizational identification along the x axis, showing how the relationship is moderated by power distance.

Comment: some examples? http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Scatterplots_(ggplot2)/

Comment: Code examples for the regression models or graphs? The regression models are just regular old lm( voice ~ variables...) type code. The graphs I have just seen in other studies as the final result, not the coding of how to construct... I have a picture of one, but am not sure how to upload here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this in ggplot. In the first example below you simply colorize the moderator variable:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = org.id, y = voice)) + geom_smooth(method = "lm", color = "black") + 
geom_point(aes(color = power.distance))
```

And in the second plot you can visualize different fits accordingly:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = org.id, y = voice)) + 
geom_smooth(aes(group = power.distance), method = "lm", se = T, 
color = "black", fullrange = T) + geom_point(aes(color = power.distance))
```